# type mismatch error is shown while passing "tName" in stringbody

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

```
val tName = System.getProperty("tName", "asdflkjh")
```

I am planning to make `"tName"` dynamic but it prints `"$tName"` in output instead of "asdflkjh".  `.body(StringBody("""{"objectId":${assetid},"objectType":"m-asset","name1": "$tName","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""))`

If I use `'session=>s'` in stringBody it throws below error `.body(StringBody(session=>s"""{"objectId":${assetid},"objectType":"m-asset","name1": "$tName","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""))`

**//////////////////////ERROR: ////////////////////////////////**

```
3894 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - type mismatch;
 found   : String("${ThumbIdList}")
 required: ?{def apply: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
 and method stringToExpression in object Predef of type [T](string: String)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])io.gatling.core.session.Expression[T]
 are possible conversion functions from String("${ThumbIdList}") to ?{def apply: ?}
3894 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ -       .foreach("${ThumbIdList}", "thumbid") {
3894 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ -                ^
3914 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - D:\myTags.scala:110: type mismatch;
 found   : String("thumbid")
 required: ?{def apply: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
 and method stringToExpression in object Predef of type [T](string: String)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])io.gatling.core.session.Expression[T]
 are possible conversion functions from String("thumbid") to ?{def apply: ?}
3914 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ -       .foreach("${ThumbIdList}", "thumbid") {
3924 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ -                                  ^
4004 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - D:\myTags.scala:98: not found: value assetid
4004 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ -           .body(StringBody(session=>s"""{"objectId":${assetid},"objectType":"m-asset","name1": "$tName","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""))
4004 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ -                                                       ^
4054 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - three errors found
4054 [main] DEBUG io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation failed (CompilerInterface)
```

**///////////// Script Starts here ///////////**

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class myTags extends Simulation {

    val testServerUrl = System.getProperty("testServerUrl", "https:someurl")
    val username = System.getProperty("username", "ma")
    val password = System.getProperty("password", "ma")
    val userCount = Integer.getInteger("userCount", 1).toInt
    val accountname = System.getProperty("accountname", "ma1")
    val tName = System.getProperty("tName", "asdflkjh")

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL(testServerUrl)

    val headers_6 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
        "If-Modified-Since" -> "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT",
        "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
        "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

    val headers_52 = Map(
        "Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
        "Origin" -> testServerUrl,
        "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
        "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Content-Type" -> "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Connection" -> "keep-alive",
        "User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36")

    val scn = scenario("Add")
        .exec(http("Fetch")
            .get("/someurl2")
            .headers(headers_6)
            .check(jsonPath("$.resources[*].ids").findAll.saveAs("IdList"))
            .check(jsonPath("$.resources[*].thumbIds").findAll.saveAs("ThumbIdList")))

        .foreach("${IdList}", "assetid") {
            exec(http("Load_Details")
            .get("/mmm/images/loader.svg")
            .resources(
            http("C1_request")
            .get("/mmm/ast/${assetid}/c1")
            .headers(headers_6),
            http("T1_request")
            .get("/mmm/ast/${assetid}/t1")
            .headers(headers_6),
            http("A1_request")
            .post("/mmm/actions")
            .headers(headers_52)
            .body(StringBody("""{"objects":[{"id":${assetid},"resource":"m-asset"}]}""")),
            http("R1_request")
            .get("/mmm/variants%3BresourceType=m-asset")
            .headers(headers_6),
            http("S1_request")
            .get("/mmm/ast/${assetid}/keyframes")
            .headers(headers_6)))

        .exec(http("Add Tags")
            .post("/mmm/objs/${assetid}/tags")
            .headers(headers_52)

            // The PROBLEM IS Here. I want to pass "$tName" dynamically
            .body(StringBody("""{"objectId":${assetid},"objectType":"m-asset","name1": "$tName","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""))
            )   
        }

        .foreach("${ThumbIdList}", "thumbid") {
            doIf(session => session("thumbid").as[String] != "-1")
            {
                exec(http("Set_Keyframes")
                .get("/mmm/keyframes/${thumbid};width=185;height=103")
                )
            }
        }

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(userCount))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is just that you already have a `$` in the string, so when you switch to string interpolation (`s"""..."""`) it's misinterpreted. Use `$$` to escape it: `s"""{"objectId":$${assetid},"objectType":"m-asset","name1": "$tName","accountId":4,"userId":5}"""`. Note that `session => ...` part is entirely orthogonal to the string interpolation.

I'll note that this is unsafe: what if `tName` contains quotes? In this case it may not be important, assuming you are going to be running the script on machines where you control the environment variables, but look up "SQL injection" and be aware the issue is not limited to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get environment variable value? If yes, try this one:

```
val tName = sys.env("tName").getOrElse(doSomething here...)
```

Comment: nope I want to fetch value of tName. Above answer of Alexey Romanov worked for me. Thanks for the reply and effort appreciated.